# Could not resolve PyPDF2

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This error is showing to me when I am importing PyPDF2 on VisualStudioCode code editor and trying to create a GUI using Tkinter this is my first GUI code and I am still learning. I am having error in importing PyPDF2. The code is-

```
                   import tkinter
                   import PyPDF2
                   from PIL import Image, ImageTK
                   
                   root = tkinter.Tk()
```

It's also showing error in the PIL one and I can't configure them out:
The error:
'''App.py C:\Users____________________\Downloads 2

---

```
                    import "PyPDF2 could not be resolved                                                  
                    Pylance(reportMissingImports) [3,8]
                    ⚠ Import could not be resolved from source 
                    Pylance(reportMissingModuleSource) [4,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Diagnostic Severity Rules](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/DIAGNOSTIC_SEVERITY_RULES.md#diagnostic-severity-rules), `reportMissingModuleSource` means

> Diagnostics for imports that have no corresponding source file. This
> happens when a type stub is found, but the module source file was not
> found, indicating that the code may fail at runtime when using this
> execution environment. Type checking will be done using the type stub.

In short, there's no such module in current used python environment.

After selecting python interpreter, open a **new integrated** Terminal then run `pip show PyPDF2`. If you get detailed information and its location is `current interpreter\lib\site-packages`, reload window should solve your question. If not, please reinstall it.